# Talmid Chacham Standing for Talmid Chacham

Tags: halacha, rabbis, standing-sitting

The Shulchan Aruch ([Yoreh De'ah 244:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.244.1?vhe=Ashlei_Ravrevei:_Shulchan_Aruch_Yoreh_Deah,_Lemberg,_1888&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)) discusses standing up out of respect for a talmid chacham-

> מצות עשה לקום מפני כל חכם אפי' אינו זקן אלא יניק וחכים ואפי' אינו רבו

Must a talmid chacham stand up for another talmid chacham?

Comment: I remember hearing a comment reported to be from the Brisker Rav that you are really standing for the Torah of the talmid chacham, not for himself. As such a talmid chacham can't refuse that his son stands for him since he stands for the Torah. If true (and it makes sense) this would suggest a t.c. should stand up for another.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29172/170

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/שולחן_ערוך_יורה_דעה_שמ_ח

Comment: re my first comment, I now asked it as a question [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100332/11501)

Answer (score 1):

Rav Chaim Kanievsky (Doleh U'mashkeh pg.267) was asked if a talmid Chacham needs to stand up for a talmid Chacham slightly greater than himself  (there are many levels ).  Rav Chaim answerd that the talmid Chacham would need to be מופלג( prominent) . In note 38 its pointed out that מופלג here doesnt mean muflag of the generation,but rather more prominent than those people in that place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming he carries himself with humility and respects other scholars (perhaps to avoid [Yevamos 62b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62b.9)) he may want to employ this similar Talmudic adage.

[Yerushalmi, Kesubos 2b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14140&st=&pgnum=219) (1.1)

> אמר רבי אלכסנדרי מיכן שאין קטן רשאי לישב עד שיאמר לו הגדול שב
>
> Rabbi Alexandri says that a smaller person may not sit until a bigger person gives him permission to do so. [Based on he verse in [Rus 4:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Ruth.4.2), וַיִּקַּ֞ח עֲשָׂרָ֧ה אֲנָשִׁ֛ים מִזִּקְנֵ֥י הָעִ֖יר וַיֹּ֣אמֶר שְׁבוּ־פֹ֑ה וַיֵּשֵֽׁבוּ׃
> Then [Boaz] took ten elders of the town and said, “Be seated here”; and they sat down.

[[Rus Rabbah:](https://www.sefaria.org/Ruth_Rabbah.7.8)]

> וַיִּקַּח עֲשָׂרָה אֲנָשִׁים מִזִּקְנֵי הָעִיר וגו' (רות ד, ד), אָמַר רַבִּי אֲלֶכְּסַנְדְּרִי מִיכָּן שֶׁאֵין רְשׁוּת לַקָּטָן לֵישֵׁב עַד שֶׁיִּתֵּן לוֹ הַגָּדוֹל רְשׁוּת.
>
> "Then [Boaz] took ten elders of the town and said, “Be seated here”; and they sat down. (Ruth 4:2)". Rabbi Alexander said: "From here it is that there is no power for the subordinate to sit until the greater authority gives it to him."